# Declarative solutions vs APEX programming - recommended way to choose the right tool

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, process-builder, architecture

Salesforce recommends to use firstly declarative solutions over the programmic ones.
But if there is something it cannot be done declaratively, then there is need to switch/use the programmic way.

But on the other hand Salesforce recommends not to mix declarative and code solutions on the same object and action.

Should then we move already declaratively created logic to the one who uses APEX after for example one action need more complex development?
For example we need to use custom validation errors in our scenario, and we had record-triggered Flows, so now we need to move everything to APEX triggers to not to mix both soultions and not risk recursive updates?

https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation
Also on this site there is recommending a little different way to design application. That is - using declarative over programmic way if it is possible is not best approach. There should be focus on the team that is working on a project and how much programmic knowledge to they have and then select desired solution (preferably always most programmic one, as it has most capabilities).

I think there are a lot of confussion about this topic now. I think it is still developing the right way to work on it, (for example switch from workflows and process builder to flows/apex - now there is no need to focus most of the time to select the best scenario from all of the 4 provided tools).

What is the best way to work/decide to use preffered solutions?

Comment: https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides are your friend.

Comment: custom validation errors now (winter 24) supported in Flows

Comment: @identigral i was mentioning this link ;p So should i take approach from this link, but not other Salesforce recomendations? ;p

Comment: @ŁukaszFranczyk You only cited one scenario where the guide was not up to date so our  answer to your question is yes, you should adhere to the guide's recommendations.